# Least-bad way to change constructor behaviour

Tags: c#, massive

I feel like I'm stuck between several bad solutions here and need some advice on how to minimize future agony. We are using Massive ORM, which in its constructor has these lines:

```
var _providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ProviderName != null)
    _providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ProviderName;

_factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_providerName);
ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
```

The important part for me here is that it reads the connection strings from `ConfigurationManager`. We are trying to centralize configuration, and in doing this we want to keep connection strings out of our web/app.configs (we have somewhere around 150 deployed hosts, so the overhead is becoming significant). However, this breaks down since the config file read is hardcoded here, and the `ConnectionStrings` collection is read only (there are workarounds, but they are all quite dirty).

One possible way out of this is to extract these lines into a virtual method and then change it with inheritance. This is not so nice when we want to update Massive though, and also calling virtual methods from a constructor is potentially bad.

What other alternatives do I have? Main priority here is to minimize impact when updating.

Comment: This sounds like an opportunity for the Service Locator pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern

Comment: @JoshC.: Yes, one alternative is to refactor it into some interface `IConfigurationManager` which has a default implementation simply uses the ConfigurationManager. I'm not certain however what the pros/cons are as compared to inheritance?

Comment: what about storing your connection strings in a separate file? would that help? (see 'Using External Configuration Files'  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we decided to make a minimal change to the massive class by making it partial. Then in a separate file, we added an additional constructor which accepted different parameters. This way, if we update the library, the only change we need to make is adding the `partial` again.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the object's configuration source dependency by passing in all required fields through the constructor.

See [Martin Fowler's article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) on Dependency Injection. The same concept applies here.